# How to merge two dataframes in PySpark where the output dataframe has alternate rows from each of the input dataframes?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two input dataframes like below:

```
ABC DEF GHI
PQR STU VWZ
SMT YUH SGR
SWI FYG LKU
```

and

```
HI HELLO HOW
ARE YOU FINE
ETC NO WORRY
SAY YOU ARE
```

Output:

```
ABC DEF GHI
HI HELLO HOW
PQR STU VWZ
ARE YOU FINE
SMT YUH SGR
ETC NO WORRY
SWI FYG LKU
SAY YOU ARE
```

How to achieve this in PySpark (Scala Spark)?

Dataframe creation scripts for convenience:

```
data1 = [('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'),
('PQR', 'STU', 'VWZ'),
('SMT', 'YUH', 'SGR'),
('SWI', 'FYG', 'LKU')]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["A", "B", "C"]

data2 = [('HI', 'HELLO', 'HOW'),
('ARE', 'YOU', 'FINE'),
('ETC', 'NO', 'WORRY'),
('SAY', 'YOU', 'ARE')]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["A1", "B1", "C1"])
```

Comment: You can achieve your result using `union` but why do you need alternative rows?

Comment: Why do you want it to be ordered as one row after other row?
Unless there is any logic you are applying which cannot be done any other way you should not do that. Also df is distributed in nature so it makes no sense doing that as it would add additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a row number to both of the dataframes and then you can union it and finally order it on row number, this will give you alternate values for the dataframe.

with row number:-

```
ABC DEF GHI 1
PQR STU VWZ 2
SMT YUH SGR 3
SWI FYG LKU 4
```

```
HI HELLO HOW 1
ARE YOU FINE 2
ETC NO WORRY 3
SAY YOU ARE 4
```

After union and order by:-

```
ABC DEF GHI 1
HI HELLO HOW 1
PQR STU VWZ 2
ARE YOU FINE 2
SMT YUH SGR 3
ETC NO WORRY 3
SWI FYG LKU 4
SAY YOU ARE 4
```

But even with this there is chance that order within the row number might vary like this:-

```
ABC DEF GHI 1
HI HELLO HOW 1
ARE YOU FINE 2
PQR STU VWZ 2
SMT YUH SGR 3
ETC NO WORRY 3
SAY YOU ARE 4
SWI FYG LKU 4
```